# Taxonomy term issue

Tags: taxonomy-terms

It is just one month that i started working on drupal8 and i am stuck with some taxonomy term issue.I created a vocabulary Skill Set and the terms included in that are: Php,.net,sql,java. In my content Jobs i have added this taxonomy Skill Set. When i select a term the id associated with it is displayed (e.g.,when i select Php,the id also is displayed as Php(23)). To overcome this issue i had installed chosen module and my problem was solved and their was no Id being displayed along with term.But the requirement is that the recruiters should be able to add new skill sets on the front end itself while posting a job and this is where i am facing the problem.When i try to post a job and add a new term to skill set(e.g., python) it displays:"no results match".Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: I don't really understand, is this a Chosen module issue or something with taxonomy?

Comment: it's a chosen module issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your field settings in the "REFERENCE TYPE" section and click on "Create referenced entities if they don't already exist"

Comment: i have tried this this option but that doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: This option add a term if it doesn't exist in the admin form of your node. Where do you want to add a term ?